# How to select only first ROW_NUMBER combined with SUM

Tags: sql-server, grouping, row-number

I like to group my table by [ID] while using SUM and also bring back 
[Product_Name] of the top `ROW_NUMBER` - not sure if I should use `ROW_NUMBER`, `GROUPING SETS` or loop through everything with FETCH... this is what I tried:

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE 
                     (
                          [ID] INT, 
                          [Price] MONEY, 
                          [Product_Name] VARCHAR(50)
                     )

INSERT INTO @SampleTable 
VALUES (1, 100, 'Product_1'), (1, 200, 'Product_2'),
       (1, 300, 'Product_3'), (2, 500, 'Product_4'),
       (2, 200, 'Product_5'), (2, 300, 'Product_6');

SELECT
    [ID],
    [Product_Name],
    [Price],
    SUM([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [Price_Total],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [Row_Number]
FROM
    @SampleTable T1
```

My desired results - only two records:

```
1   Product_1   100.00   600.00     1
2   Product_4   500.00  1000.00     1
```

Any help or guidance is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I end up using what Prateek Sharma suggested in his comment, to simply wrap the query with another SELECT WHERE [Row_Number] = 1

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        [ID]
        ,[Product_Name]
        ,[Price]
        ,SUM([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [Price_Total]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [Row_Number]
    FROM @SampleTable
) MultipleRows
WHERE [Row_Number] = 1
```

Comment: BTW - Nicely formatted question.  Easy copy/paste

Comment: There is no " top ROW_NUMBER" unless you have a column that defines ordering.

Comment: I mean top row from the result set (in case there is more than one with the same ID)

Comment: As ordered by what? There is no guaranteed top row from the resultset without any ordering criteria applied

Comment: Thanks Martin, I see your point now, in my case it is not important but good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a column on which you will perform `ORDER BY` for `ROW_NUMBER()`. In this case if you want to only rely on the table self index then it's OK to use ID column for ORDER BY.

Hence your query is correct and you can go with it.

Other option is to use `WITH TIES` clause. BUT again, If you will use **WITH TIES** clause with the ORDER BY on ID column then performance will be very poor. `WITH TIES` only performs well if you have well defined index. And, then can use that indexed column with WITH TIES clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM (
         SELECT [ID]
               ,[Product_Name]
               ,[Price]
               ,SUM([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [Price_Total]
         FROM @SampleTable
     ) TAB
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY <IndexedColumn> DESC)
```

This query may help you bit. But remember, it is also not going to provide better performance than the query written by you. It is only reducing the line of code.

Comment: I was trying to add WHERE [Row_Number] = 1 to pick up just the top level of results - but it's not working...

Comment: Use This -
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT
  [ID]
  ,[Product_Name]
  ,[Price]
  ,SUM([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [Price_Total]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS [Row_Number]
 FROM
  @SampleTable 
 ) TAB
WHERE [Row_Number] = 1

Comment: Oh cool - that works too! maybe more efficient from WITH TIES? checking...

Comment: WITH TIES is not efficient, that's why DBA max time avoid to use it. When your DB has a proper structure, with all the best practices used in your DB architecture, then also only for the complex queries we use it.You can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using the **WITH TIES** clause.  No extra field RN.

Hopefully, you have a proper sequence number or date which can be used in either the `sum() over` or in the final `row_number() over`

**Example**

```
SELECT Top 1 with ties *
 From (
        Select [ID]
              ,[Product_Name]
              ,[Price]
              ,SUM([Price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]) AS [Price_Total]
        FROM @SampleTable T1
      ) A 
Order By  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Price_Total] Desc)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Product_Name    Price   Price_Total
1   Product_1       100.00  600.00
2   Product_4       500.00  1000.00
```

Comment: This is not efficient

Comment: @Yovav I like the WITH TIES.  There are many ways to do this. For example a subquery to get Price Total by ID.   Also as a cte or sub-query where RN=1.

Comment: @Yovav RE: efficiency because a simple filter on row number = 1 is more efficient than calculating the row number anyway and then sorting the whole result set with that as a sort column.

Comment: @Yovav Martin is indeed correct.  However, in my benchmark tesing, the with ties was a very close second.   The WITH TIES is just another tool in your belt.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "top ROW_NUMBER" unless you have a column that defines ordering.

If you just want an arbitary row per id you can use the below. To deterministically pick one you would need to order by deterministic unique criteria.

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE
(
ID             INT,
Price          MONEY,
Product_Name   VARCHAR(50),
INDEX cix CLUSTERED (ID)
);

INSERT INTO @SampleTable
VALUES      (1,100,'Product_1'),
            (1,200,'Product_2'),
            (1,300,'Product_3'),
            (2,500,'Product_4'),
            (2,200,'Product_5'),
            (2,300,'Product_6');


WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       OrderingColumn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM @SampleTable
)

SELECT ID,
       SUBSTRING(MIN(CONCAT(STR(OrderingColumn), Product_Name)), 11, 50)         AS Product_Name,
       CAST(SUBSTRING(MIN(CONCAT(STR(OrderingColumn), Price)), 11, 50) AS MONEY) AS Price,
       SUM(Price)                                                                AS Price_Total
FROM   T
GROUP  BY ID
```

The plan for this is pretty efficient as it is able to use the index ordered by `id` and has no additional sorts, spools, or passes through the table.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what I mean is - if there is more than one result for the same ID then - the first result is the top record that I would like to get for all the data that is not summed up (like [Product_Name] etc.)

Comment: @Yovav - you keep saying "first" and "top" but you haven't addressed the point - which multiple people have told you - that there is no inherent "first" or "top"

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, it wasn't clear enough, in my case I just needed the first record that appears (the top level where [Row_Number] = 1) without any particular ordering, but I will probably put some good use to your answer at some point too.